# Tomcat : How to redirect external ip address access to an other location

Tags: tomcat, redirect, nginx, ip, port

I have a NGINX and Tomcat server. I want to allow only localhost to access on my Tomcat.

On the server.xml I put this tag :

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
           addConnectorPort="true"
           allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+;\d*|::1;\d*|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;\d*"
           denyStatus="404"/>
```

But now I want to redirect users who want to access directly on my tomcat to NGINX (on port 80).

I try to put this tag on the Tomcat conf/web.xml :

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code> <!-- 404 is the denyStatus of the previous conf-->
    <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And the 404.html contains a basic redirection to the NGINX. But Tomcat never redirect to this page. (I try to put the html on webapps and conf directories).

Is this the good option to do that kind of redirection or there is another one ? I'm not an expert, I'm looking for an easy way.

My OS is Windows 2012. The other way can be something like iptables on Linux.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your users by putting the following into the server configuration file of nginx:

```
error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
```

It will redirect all users that face a 404 error to index.html and convert the 404 response code to a 200 OK HTTP Response.

Comment: I try to redirect users who want to access directly to Tomcat by http://myserver:8080/. NGINX can't help at this level I think.

Comment: You could use PHP e.g. to check wether the request comes from localhost and if not throw a 403 error and use the following code in your NGINX configuration: `error_page 404 =200 /index.html;`

Comment: I'm looking for a Tomcat configuration or something like a redirection port like iptables do but on windows.